# Quick question on free fall of 2 objects

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity

I am trying to work through a problem, that is basically telling me that two objects were dropped from a building, one was thrown 2 seconds after the previous object, and I have to find out how long it takes for these two objects to be a certain length apart (15 meters for example).

My first guess at this was to use the $y = vt + 0.5at^2$ formula,
which would give me the distance the first object travelled before the second object was thrown. I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Why dont you apply that equation to the second object too?

Comment: The problem is I am not sure where to go after calculating the distance of the first object after 2 seconds. If I applied the equation to the second object wouldn't the answer be the same as the first object when I calculated it?

Comment: But the $t$ in the second one will be $t-2$

Comment: Thank you for your help I really do appreciate it. I am just very confused still although I kind of understand what you mean.... the first object I did;
Y = 0 + (9.80 m/s^2)(2)^2....how do you mean change the second to t - 2 -?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is correct, now simply add indices to everything, i.e.

$$y_i = v_{0,i}t_i + \frac12 a_it_i^2\quad\text{where } i\in\{1,2\}$$

and note that $t_2 = t_1 - 2\,\text{s}$. Then solve $15\,\text{m}\stackrel!=y_1 - y_2$.

Comment: I appreciate this thank you! I have never done physics before and this is my first week, so I am honestly clueless with it. I am trying to understand what you mean so thank you

Comment: You're welcome - it might be nice to add some information on your background to the question or your user profile, e.g. whether you're on high school, know about indices and the like etc.

Comment: I need to do that. I am in University but never took a physics class in high school! What are y1 and y2? Thank you!

Comment: $y_1$ and $y_2$ describe the position of objects 1 and 2 respectively, and the same applies to the initial velocities $v_{0,1}$ and $v_{0,2}$ (which vanish in your case), accelerations $a_1=a_2=g$ and times $t:=t_1=t_2-2\,\text{s}$. In general, you label (or enumerate) multiple objects and add the same label to their variables (coordinates etc)

Comment: you're welcome. Don't forget you can mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem. And welcome to physics.SE! If you like it here, please take [the tour](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour) for a quick introduction, and for formulae you'll definitely enjoy using [LaTeX](http://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you take the time of throwing of the first object as $0$ then the second object will start  falling  at $0+2$ second.Now for the second one take the time of its start of fall as 0 and so the ending time will be 2 sec less i.e$0+2 \longrightarrow 0$ and$t \longrightarrow  t-2$

So for the second one $$ \frac {dx} {dt} =u+at$$
$$ dx=udt +atdt$$
$$\int^y_0 dx=\int^{t-2}_0  udt+atdt$$

After you integrate with this limits your second equation will come out with $t-2$ .

Comment: ahh I see what you mean now thank you for explaining it :)

Comment: And the answer you accepted is wrong it will be $t-2$ not $t+2$

Comment: @soumyadeep That depends on whether you label the first particle to be dropped as "1" or the upper one ;) but you're right, I fixed that